# JsHint: .jshintrc not working

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp, jshint

I am getting error regarding 'angular' was used before it declared.
I have tried to declare it in .jshintrc as per below

```
"globals": {
    "angular": true
}
```

but still I am getting an error.
Also I am getting error of 'alert' is undefined even I have keept below setting in .jshintrc

```
"browser": true,
```

Could you please help me setting in .jshintrc is not working. What I am doing wrong.
I have also tried to add /*global angular*/ at top of file but after adding to the file I am getting error of 
Unsupported rule: validateJSDoc:
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Are you using grunt or gulp or just your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/cfjedimaster/brackets-jshint/.

Or maybe the answer of this question [Adobe Brackets disable jslint but allow jshint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584301/adobe-brackets-disable-jslint-but-allow-jshint) will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

According to [JSHint Documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/) globals can be defined inline at the beginning of your JavaScript files like this:

```
/* globals Angular */
```

Or in a the .jshintrc JSON object like this:

```
{
  ....,
  "predef": [ "angular" ]
}
```

prefed means *predefiend*. You should include all the globals you are using in this array.

Comment: i have tried to declare global in .jshintrc but some how it is not getting in consideration.i have already mention that in my question.

Comment: @Sagarpatel you didn't mention you that you tried `"predef": [ "angular" ]` ... Good luck

Comment: yes i havn't mentioned that "predef":["angular"]  i used. but i mentioned that i have tried to declare in .jshintrc but somehow all the setting inside that file is not getting into consideration.